# Python - can't upload files on FTP

Tags: python-3.x, ftp

I'm writing a function to load files into a specific folder of an FTP area, I get an error on "storbinary" line.
PS: "Filename" is a global variable

import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP

```
host = "ftp.test.com"
username = "usr"
password = "pwd"

# connect to ftp
ftp = FTP(host=host, user=username, passwd=password)

# set upload directory
ftp.cwd('Test')

# upload file
with open(os.path.join('/root/ftp/output/', Filename), 'w') as fp:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % os.path.basename(Filename), fp, 1024)
```

error message : ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % os.path.basename(Filename), fp, 1024) File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 506, in storbinary buf = fp.read(blocksize)

Comment: error message :    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % os.path.basename(Filename), fp, 1024)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 506, in storbinary
    buf = fp.read(blocksize)

Comment: I do not see any *"error message"*. Edit full exception callstack into your question. Do not post information in comments.

Comment: should be ok now

Comment: No it's not. There's **no error message**. It's just a reference to a statement in your code. Show us a complete output. Also set `FTP.set_debuglevel` and post a complete ftplib log.

Answer (score -1):

```
    host = "ftp.test.com"
username = "urs"
password = "pwd"

# FTP connection
ftp = FTP(host=host, user=username, passwd=password)

# change upload directory 
ftp.cwd('test')

# upload file
upload_file = os.path.join('/root/test/ftp/', Filename)
with open(upload_file, 'rb') as fp:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % os.path.basename(upload_file), fp)
fp.close()

# print the content of directory   
print(ftp.dir())
```

Comment: What is this? Is this a solution?

Comment: So would you explain in your answer what does the fix involve? For me, the only differences are 1) The absence of the `1024` argument. But I do not see how that could help. 2) A different path: `/root/test/ftp/` vs `/root/ftp/output/` – Is that the fix?